# 'can't assign to function call' Error message

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use a for loop to populate a 2D array however keep getting a 'can't assign to function call' error. I am trying to store the new value for xa in each loop in a new row each iteration. xa is a function that changes with each loop representing the number of particles left of A in a radioactive decay with time.

I later want to be able to take the average of each row and store this into a new array.

```
    A_values = numpy.zeros([20, 402])

    for i in range(0,20):

        xa = numpy.concatenate([evolve_system(NA, NB, NC, rules1, nsteps)[0], evolve_system(final_NA, final_NB, final_NC, rules2, nsteps)[0]])

        A_values([i]) = xa
```

error message:

```
' File "<ipython-input-62-e1d800a3aed8>", line 40
    A_values([i]) = xa
        ^

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call'
```

Comment: `A_values[i]` without parentheses.

Comment: Why do you have the parentheses around the brackets? I guess you meant to write `A_values[i]`?

Comment: Thank you both so much been stuck on this for ages!